# Implementing a buffer-like structure in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, data-structures, message-queue

I'm trying to write a small wsgi application which will put some objects to an external queue after each request. I want to make this in batch, ie. make the webserver put the object to a buffer-like structure in memory, and another thread and/or process for sending these objects to the queue in batch, when buffer is big enough or after certain timeout, and clearing the buffer. I don't want to be in NIH syndrome and not want to bother with threading stuff, however I could not find a suitable code for this job. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Examine https://docs.python.org/library/queue.html to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: beat me by 16 seconds to the same answer. I think that's what he wants too, but couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: Here is what I like most about Python: the 80% of what you're going to implement is already out there. Often, even in the standard library.

Comment: And this question has already been asked on SO.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394500/is-there-a-simple-way-in-python-to-create-a-file-which-can-be-written-to-in-one-t

Comment: I know this is a 5-year old thread, but apparently still relevant (since I just found it looking for a buffer-like structure in Python)... I wanted to report that the above link to python.org is no longer valid if anyone cares to update it, if possible. I did find http://pymotw.com/2/Queue/ as a possible replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Since you write "thread and/or *process*", see also [multiprocessing.Queue and multiprocessing.JoinableQueue](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) from 2.6. Those are interprocess variants of Queue.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [buffered stream](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase) if you are using python 3.0.

Comment: Look like it's [available](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase) for Python 2 as well.